# Athena Query: No viable alternative at input 'array(select'

Tags: amazon-athena, presto, trino

I am running a simple aws athena query as follows

```
SELECT elements,
    ARRAY(SELECT v * 2
          FROM UNNEST(elements) AS v) AS multiplied_elements
FROM (
    VALUES
        (ARRAY[1, 2]),
        (ARRAY[1, 3, 9]),
        (ARRAY[1, 4, 16, 64])
) AS t(elements)
```

The query is directly taken from a blog in the official prestodb website: https://prestodb.io/blog/2020/03/02/presto-lambda

But on running the query I am running into

```
line 2:11: no viable alternative at input 'array(select' (service: amazonathena; status code: 400; error code: invalidrequestexception; request id: 3fec5bf2-571a-45b0-8771-a860b6e840ec; proxy: null)
```

What is the reason for this error?

Answer (score 2):

Presto and Athena (which is based on a very old version of Presto) don't actually support that syntax. In [recent versions](https://trino.io/docs/current/release/release-353.html) of Trino ([formerly known as Presto SQL](https://trino.io/blog/2020/12/27/announcing-trino.html)), you can almost do that, except for the lack of "[array by table subquery constructor](https://github.com/trinodb/trino/issues/12)" syntax:

```sql
SELECT 
    elements,
    ( -- this is a correlated scalar subquery 
        SELECT array_agg(v * 2)
        FROM UNNEST(elements) AS u(v)
    ) AS multiplied_elements
FROM (
    VALUES
        (ARRAY[1, 2]),
        (ARRAY[1, 3, 9]),
        (ARRAY[1, 4, 16, 64])
) AS t(elements);
```

It outputs:

```
    elements    | multiplied_elements
----------------+---------------------
 [1, 2]         | [2, 4]
 [1, 3, 9]      | [2, 6, 18]
 [1, 4, 16, 64] | [2, 8, 32, 128]
(3 rows)
```